# Prove that : $(BN)//(DM)$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Problem :

Let $ABCD$ a square with $AB=1$ and $BMC،DNC$ equilateral triangles such $M$ inside the square and $N$ outside square

Prove that : $(BN)//(DM)$

My attempt :

take axes $(A,\vec{AB},\vec{AD})$

Then I'm going to find the coordinates of $N,M,B,D$

$B(0,1),D(1,0)$ now $M,N$

$x_{M}=\cos \frac{π}{3}=\frac{1}{2}$ , $y_{M}=1-\cos \frac{π}{6}=\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2}$

So : $M\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$

Same method we find we obtaine :

$N\left(\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Now :

$m_{BN}=\frac{\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}=-\sqrt{3}$

$m_{DM}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Conclusion : $m_{BN}.m_{DM}=-1$ this mean $(DM)//(BN)$

This is my way I need see different way for example by angles or similar triangle Homothetic transformation or rotational or barycenter for example

I have already to see your hints [image]

Answer (score 1):

Using your diagram as reference,

1. $\triangle NBC$ is isosceles, therefore $\angle NBC = 15^\circ$.
2. $\triangle MDC$ is isosceles, therefore $\angle MDC = 75^\circ$.
3. Then you have $\angle ADM = 15^\circ$.
4. From 1., 2., and $AD\parallel BC$, you derive the thesis.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be the midpoint of $DM$ and let $Q$ be the intersection of $CP$ and $BN$. Let $E$ be the intersection of $BN$ and $CM$, and $F$ be that of $BN$ and $CD$.

Since $CM=CD$, it is clear that $CP\perp DM$ and $CP$ bisects $\angle MCD$.

Since $CB=CN$, we have 
$$\tag{1}\angle CBN=\angle CNB.$$
Since $\angle BCM=\angle DCN=60^\circ$, we have
$$\tag{2}\angle ECN=\angle ECF+\angle DCN=\angle ECF+\angle BCM=\angle BCF.$$
$(1)$, $(2)$, and the fact that $BC=CN$, implies that 
$$\triangle BCF\text{ and }\triangle NCE\text{ are congruent},$$
from which we deduce that 
$$\tag{3} BF=NE.$$
Since $BF=BE+EF$ and $NE=NF+EF$, $(3)$ implies that 
$$\tag{4} BE=FH.$$
Using $(1)$, $(4)$, and the condition that $BC=CN$, one gets that
$$\triangle BEC\text{ and }\triangle NFC\text{ are congruent},$$
which yields that $CE=CF$, and so $\triangle ECF$ is an isosceles triangle. Since $CP$ bisects $\angle ECF$, we see that $CQ\perp EF$.

Since both $DM$ and $NB$ are perpendicular to $CP$, it follows that $DM\parallel BN$. $\mathbf{Q.E.D.}$

Comment: Since you use the fact that $CN\cong CB$ and $CM\cong CD$, might as well get directly to the thesis using isosceles triangles, might it not?